# Connecting iOS App to USB Flash Drive

Tags: ios, usb-drive

All,

We are developing a iPhone app, It has feature to generate a txt/pdf file and copy it to a USB flash drive for future purpose. I know we need to have MFI license to have a USB device. Are there any providers who can provide the device and SDK, so that we can integrate to our own app. Or

If we have any USB drive can we use iOS SDK to write the files?

Please let me know if any thing is possible.

Comment: can you check this?
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html

Comment: @kiri did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @kiri did you find any solution to this?